# How to extract parameters names from SQL statement using regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to extract the parameters names from a query like this:

```
select * from table where a = :param1 and b = :param2
```

I wrote this expression:`"(?<param>:\w* )"`

It gives me `:param1` twice

Note: It's in a C#.Net application.

Any Help !!

Thanks

Comment: What language is running the Regular Expression: Perl, Java, etc. This can alter the syntax slightly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this C# code - it fetches two matches, one for `:param1` and another for `:param2`

```
Regex getParamRegex = new Regex(@"(?<param>:\w*)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

string input = "select * from table where a = :param1 and b = :param2";

var allMatches = getParamRegex.Matches(input);

foreach (var match in allMatches)
{
   string work = match.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks marc_s, I had a problem in C# fetching code, I was fetch matches using Groups collection by group name, now It's ok.